# ¿Cómo modificar las rutas de mi proyecto sin dañar su estructura? en php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, rutas, composer

estoy teniendo la siguiente inquietud,

Tengo mi proyecto en la siguiente estructura

```
my-proyect
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── HomeController.php
│   ├── models
│   │   └── ...
│   └── views
│       ├── home
│       │   └── index.php
│       └── layouts
│           ├── header.php
│           ├── footer.php
│           ├── css-link.php
│           └── js-link.php
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── style.css
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── script.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── images
│   │   └── logo.png
│   └── index.php
└── config
    └── conexion.php
```

Ahora quisiera saber si hay alguna posibilidad de que al ingresar en la URL **http://localhost/my-proyect/home** me muestre todo el contenido de la pagina de inicio ubicado en la carpeta home de views, y así sucesivamente con los demás vistas que existan, obviamente considerando el archivo index.php de la carpeta public ya que mi idea es no considerar public en la URL.

Creo que se le conoce como URL amigables